# Function to add a node with a unique ID and x,y coordinates

Tags: python

This here is a function that adds a graph node, with a unique id to an x,y matrix.

The rules are that :

- The node id must be unique
- Only one node can exist at a given coordinate.

Here's my function that attempts to add a node with given id, at given x y coordinates .

```
def addNode(self, node_id, x, y):
    if self.node_list[node_id] != None:
        raise exception("This node ID already exists.")
    else:
        if self.spacialMatrix[x][y] != None:
            raise exception("This node position is already populated.")
        else:               
            self.spacialMatrix[x][y] = node_id
            self.node_list[node_id] = [x,y]
```

How else would I do this?

I generally prefer keeping an if/else structure (so that you know that you are capturing all branches of your logic flow, rather than leaving unhandled else conditions).

Comment: This looks like Python to me, right?

Comment: @nhgrif Yes - but it's a pretty code agnostic question.

Comment: There's no such thing as code agnostic questions on Code Review since we require actual working, real code.  Questions here require a language tag.

Comment: This excerpt still lacks context, in my opinion. You should show the rest of the class, or at least the constructor. Also, how is this method used by the caller? How does it pick a `node_id`? Is `node_list` really a list? How large is it? Too many unanswered questions for a decent review.

Answer (score 3):

```
def addNode(self, node_id, x, y):
    if self.node_list[node_id] != None:
```

Since `None` is a guaranteed singleton, you could use `is not None` rather than `!= None`.

```
        raise exception("This node ID already exists.")
```

If this exception is quite common, assuming this code is part of a tree structure of some sort, you could write a custom exception such as `NodeError` to handle all such error - that'd be neat.

```
else:
```

Is it necessary to have the `else` here? If the `if` clause above raises an exception, this block won't be executed anyway; so I'd suggest you should remove this and unindent the code below.

```
    if self.spacialMatrix[x][y] != None:
        raise exception("This node position is already populated.")
```

Same thing I mentioned above - `is not None` and `NodeError` exception. Also, wouldn't the wrong `x` and `y` arguments raise an `IndexError`? Have you done anything else in the code to ensure that this won't happen?

```
    else:               
        self.spacialMatrix[x][y] = node_id
        self.node_list[node_id] = [x,y]
```

This part looks good.

My suggestions:

```
class NodeError(exception):
    """
    For node related errors.
    """
    pass

def addNode(self, node_id, x, y):
    if self.node_list[node_id] is not None:
        raise NodeError("This node ID already exists.")
    if self.spacialMatrix[x][y] is not None:
        raise NodeError("This node position is already populated.")
    self.spacialMatrix[x][y] = node_id
    self.node_list[node_id] = [x,y]
```

*Note: Adding doc strings would be a very good idea!*

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether it's a bug or a runtime error for those `None` checks to fail. If it could happen at runtime, then @Renae's answer would be the way to go. If you're signalling conditions that should *never* happen except due to a bug (i.e. this function is an internal implementation detail), then I'd `assert` instead:

```
def addNode(self, node_id, x, y):
    assert self.node_list[node_id] is None
    assert self.spacialMatrix[x][y] is None

    self.spacialMatrix[x][y] = node_id
    self.node_list[node_id] = [x, y]
```